# Registering a protocol with wxWebViewHandler

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am currently trying to implement an app that makes excessive use of wxWebView. I use static pages as well as dynamic pages that are stored/cached on the user's PC. For the application, I wish to use two schemes / protocols:

`static://` and `profile://`

The goal is to have them handle local content but making addressing them easier. 
For example the translation code for static sites:

```
wxString Mainframe::GetStaticContent(wxString file)
{
    // Choose based on language
    wxString language = wxGetApp().GetSelectedLanguage();

    // Construct Filename
    wxFileName fname(wxGetApp().GetAppPath() + wxString("/static/") + language + wxString("/") + file + wxString(".html"));

    // Return full path, which is corrected by wxWidgets
    return fname.GetFullPath();
}
```

An url to use this would look like that:

```
static://start
```

Now I have a class which derives from wxWebViewHandler to make this happen:

```
class WebViewHandlerStatic : public wxWebViewHandler
{
public:
    WebViewHandlerStatic(const wxString& protocol, Mainframe* parent)
        : wxWebViewHandler(protocol), m_parent(parent)
    {
        m_fs = new wxFileSystem();
    }

    virtual WebViewHandlerStatic::~WebViewHandlerStatic()
    {
        wxDELETE(m_fs);
    }

    virtual wxFSFile* GetFile (const wxString &uri)
    {
        wxString content = uri.substr(9, uri.length()).BeforeLast('/');
        wxString path = m_parent->GetStaticContent(content);

        if ( wxFileName::FileExists(path) && wxFileSystem::HasHandlerForPath(path) )
        {           
            //path = wxFileSystem::FileNameToURL(path);
            return m_fs->OpenFile(path);
        }
        else
            return NULL;
    }   

private:
    Mainframe* m_parent;
    wxFileSystem* m_fs;
};
```

However, the problem is that if I click the link static://about or any other with that protocol, nothing happens. I tried it with and without FilenameToURL(). I also checked in the debugger, the path is valid after its construction. But the page does not change.

Anyone having any insight into this?

edit:

Temporary Workaround:

```
class WebViewHandlerStatic : public wxWebViewHandler
{
public:
    WebViewHandlerStatic(const wxString& protocol, Mainframe* parent)
        : wxWebViewHandler(protocol), m_parent(parent)
    {
        //m_fs = new wxFileSystem();
    }

    virtual WebViewHandlerStatic::~WebViewHandlerStatic()
    {
        //wxDELETE(m_fs);
    }

    virtual wxFSFile* GetFile (const wxString &uri)
    {
        wxString content = uri.substr(9, uri.length()).BeforeLast('/');
        wxFileName path = m_parent->GetStaticContent(content);
        wxString url = path.GetFullPath();

        if ( wxFileSystem::HasHandlerForPath(url) )
        {
            m_parent->LoadURL(url);
                    // The content of url is in this state: "d:\Source\wxSteamStats\bin\static\en_GB\about.html" (Copied from debugger)
        }
        return NULL;
    }   

private:
    Mainframe* m_parent;
    wxFileSystem* m_fs;
};
```

This works flawless without any exceptions. So I am not really sure why wxFileSystem is needed here at all or how it works inside. I looked at the code of the component, but I am not familiar with the API of IE. To me, it looks like the actual document is never given to IE. Or do I have to "feed" the source somewhere to the control? I could not spot something like this in the sourcecode of wxArchiveWebHandler or the sample.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this by using the following class which makes a few minor changes to yours.

```
class WebViewHandlerStatic : public wxWebViewHandler
{
public:
    WebViewHandlerStatic(const wxString& protocol) : wxWebViewHandler(protocol)
    {
        m_fs = new wxFileSystem();
    }

    virtual WebViewHandlerStatic::~WebViewHandlerStatic()
    {
        wxDELETE(m_fs);
    }

    virtual wxFSFile* GetFile (const wxString &uri)
    {
        wxFileName path = "C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/doc.htm";
        wxString url = wxFileSystem::FileNameToURL(path);

        if (wxFileSystem::HasHandlerForPath(url))        
            return m_fs->OpenFile(url);
        else
            return NULL;
    }   
private:
    wxFileSystem* m_fs;
};
```

I then registered it as per the other example in the sample and it worked just fine. The main difference is that I used `wxFileSystem::FileNameToURL` as wxFileSystem expects a URI as opposed to a file path. I suspect when you uncomment your call to it there is some dodgy implicit conversion going on as you pass a wxString and not a wxFileName. Try returning `fname` from `Mainframe::GetStaticContent` then calling `FileNameToURL` on that and hopefully it'll work.

Comment: On a personal note it is cool to see people using this as it was my Google Summer of Code project this year :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change anything. What I now get is "First-chance exception at 0x753cb9bc in wxSteamStats-d.exe: 0xE0000001: 0xe0000001." But I cannot debug it, since no code is available then, looks like inside IE.

Comment: Sorry for comment spam, but you made it? Thanks a ton man, it is very appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I did, I'm glad you like it! That is an intriguing error, could you try the wxWebView sample, it is the the sample directory of your wxWidgets install. It takes paths like the following for local files: wxfs:///C:/Users/Steven/Desktop/doc.htm Do you get any errors with it?

Comment: If I enter wxfs:///d:/Source/wxSteamStats/bin/static/en_GB/about.html into the sample app, nothing happens at all. Busy Cursor forever and "Stop" does not seem to do anything. I am on Win7 64bit and I am using it with static libraries, if that does make a difference.  Visual C++ 2008

Comment: Ok, that is interesting, probably best if you file a bug at http://trac.wxwidgets.org with as much information as possible and I'll take a deeper look at it. If you could step though the code in src/msw/webview_ie.cpp with a debugger that would be even better, VirtualProtocol::Start or VirtualProtocol::Read would be good places for breakpoints.

Comment: I have created the ticket, see http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13907 . Thanks :)